# Getting " No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it."

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ivy

I am running a test on AWS through jenkins integration, this test requires a file to be uploaded, and to upload a file a upload(File Explorer) window is opened, which is triggering the error

---

[java] [INFO ] [2:53:49PM] Thread-1 (TestMethodRunner.java:188) - 
     [java] No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
     [java] [INFO ] [2:53:49PM] Thread-1 (TestMethodRunner.java:189) - java.awt.HeadlessException: 
     [java] No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
     [java]     at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getSystemClipboard(HeadlessToolkit.java:307)
     [java]     at com.proquest.apps.etd.pqaf.layer.FileUploadWindow.uploadingFile(FileUploadWindow.java:50)
     [java]     at com.proquest.apps.etd.regression.tests.SmokeTest.smokeTest(SmokeTest.java:100)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
     [java]     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
     [java]     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
     [java]     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
     [java]     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
     [java]     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
     [java]     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
     [java]     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
     [java]     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
     [java]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
     [java]     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
     [java]     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
     [java]     at com.proquest.testing.TestMethodRunner.runUnitTest(TestMethodRunner.java:194)
     [java]     at com.proquest.testing.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:62)
     [java]     at com.proquest.testing.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:13)

---

1. How to resolve this error, I can't use putty to enable X11, the tests are ran through Jenkins , the test is executed every day automatically at the scheduled time, so i have to make it dynamic?
2. Is there any ivy dependency for the "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set and Headless Exception" that can be used.

Answer (score 5):

If your build requires X11 access, you'll want to wrap your jenkins build with a virtual frame buffer. Jenkins has an available plugin to help with this called [Xvfb](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin).

Then you'll want to let Jenkins know to use this new display for your tests instead.

example:

`export DISPLAY=:1.0`

where `1.0` would be the name of your virtual X window.

Comment: and if i want to not run chrome in headless mode ?